# Hot to change default_suffix in zend-expressive?

Tags: php, mezzio

I have one problem - I need to change `default_suffix` from `phtml` on something else... 
How I can do it?
I find file where it is -

> \Zend\Expressive\ZendView\NamespacedPathStackResolver.php

But how I can change it? I don't find where I can may write something like

> $foo->setDefaultSuffix('html')

Maybe, I can write something in `config.php` file?

Comment: Which version of zend expressive are we talking here?

Comment: zend-expressive 3

Comment: So, solution is in github issue [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive/issues/641)